# Shuffling a deck of cards

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, shuffle

I'm making a Deck class for a C++ program. It needs to have two methods: one to pop a card off the top of the deck, another to shuffle the deck. I'm concerned with the latter.

Cards are represented as integers 1 to 52 inclusive. What is the fastest algorithm to shuffle the deck (assuming a 'good' level of randomness)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you wish to implement the shuffle yourself, a very straightforward but also functional shuffling algorithm: [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

> To shuffle an array a of n elements:
>
> ```
> for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
>    j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
>    exchange a[j] and a[i]
> ```

Of course, the C++ standard library also has things like this implemented for you, such as [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), included via the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: (As an aside, I'm fairly sure that the standard implementation of `std::random_shuffle` *is* a Fisher–Yates shuffle.)

Comment: Shuffle is easy **once** you know how to do it. It is very easy to get it wrong if you have not studied randomness in a maths class.

Comment: @Martin: it's very easy to get wrong if you can't follow simple instructions ;-p

Comment: @Steve: Even I have a hard time reading the above and I know what Amber is trying to say. The only easy way is to use a pre-built algorithm. I bet if we asked 10 people with a score under a 1000 to implement it in C++ 2 would get it wrong. Please send all submissions to Steve. :-0

Comment: There's also a nice blog post which explains the [intuition behind Fisher-Yates Shuffling](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/05/28/the-intuition-behind-fisher-yates-shuffling/)

Comment: `for i from n − 1 downto 1`: By any chance, the `a[0]` has a high probability of being the same value? why not `downto 0`?

Comment: @Han `a[0]` can be swapped in any iteration of the loop if `j = 0`. If `i` were equal to zero then `j` would have to also be equal to zero (because the first line of the loop body would set `j` to a random integer less than or equal to zero) which wouldn't change the ordering at all.

Answer (score 8):

Use `std::random_shuffle` to shuffle the deck.

Answer (score 4):

std::random_shuffle

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/