# Deck of Cards: How do I make it so I randomly draw a card only once?

Tags: c++

I am trying to simulate a deck of cards but I don't know how to make it so it randomly chooses a card but only once. I keep getting doubles of cards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> //for rand and srand
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string suit[] = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs" };
string facevalue[] = { "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
        "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };

string getcard() {
    string card;
    int cardvalue = rand() % 13;
    int cardsuit = rand() % 4;

    card += facevalue[cardvalue];
    card += " of ";
    card += suit[cardsuit];

    return card;
}

int main() {
    int numberofcards = 52;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofcards; i++) {
        cout << "You drew a " << getcard() << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: After selection, delete. Is it any good?

Comment: Push the cards into a *queue* after shuffle, and draw from that. The data structure for your queue can be simpler than you may first think. i.e. an index into the shuffled deck that walks forward with each draw.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075439/shuffling-a-deck-of-cards

Answer (score 4):

Its a deck of cards. Just do this:

1. Initialize the deck. Layout all 52 cards within a fixed 52-card array.
2. Shuffle the deck.
3. Start the drawing loop by initializing a `nextCard` index into your deck starting at zero (0). With each 'draw' (the card at `deck[nextCard]`) advance `nextCard` by one. When `nextCard` == 52, you're out of cards.

Following is a sample of how to setup the deck. I leave the `nextCard` indexing and drawing algorithm to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// names of ranks.
static const char *ranks[] =
{
    "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
    "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"
};

// name of suites
static const char *suits[] =
{
    "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"
};

void print_card(int n)
{
    cout << ranks[n % 13] << " of " << suits[n / 13] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int deck[52];

    // Prime, shuffle, dump
    for (int i=0;i<52;deck[i++]=i);
    random_shuffle(deck, deck+52);
    for_each(deck, deck+52, print_card);

    return 0;
}
```

A sample of the deck-dump is below:

```
Seven of Diamonds
Five of Hearts
Nine of Diamonds
Ten of Diamonds
Three of Diamonds
Seven of Clubs
King of Clubs
Five of Diamonds
Ace of Spades
Four of Spades
Two of Diamonds
Five of Clubs
Queen of Diamonds
Six of Spades
Three of Hearts
Ten of Spades
Two of Clubs
Ace of Hearts
Four of Hearts
Four of Diamonds
Ace of Diamonds
Six of Diamonds
Jack of Clubs
King of Spades
Jack of Diamonds
Four of Clubs
Eight of Diamonds
Queen of Hearts
King of Hearts
Ace of Clubs
Three of Spades
Two of Spades
Six of Clubs
Seven of Hearts
Nine of Clubs
Jack of Hearts
Nine of Hearts
Eight of Clubs
Ten of Clubs
Five of Spades
Three of Clubs
Queen of Clubs
Seven of Spades
Eight of Spades
Ten of Hearts
King of Diamonds
Jack of Spades
Six of Hearts
Queen of Spades
Nine of Spades
Two of Hearts
Eight of Hearts
```

Comment: For (2), there's no reason not to use a proper randomization algorithm.

Comment: I particularly like this answer because it is more simulation-oriented: you never lose information, so you could replay the draw of cards forward and, if you wish, backwards.

Comment: @AricTenEyck: In particular in C++ [`random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/)

Comment: @Matt It can be exploited even beyond that, esp if you are limited on the back side of the draw. Example: You have a game that always draws five cards. once you reach 50, there are not five left. At that point you can reshuffle *just* [0..49]. If your `nextCard` increment is actually `nextCard = (nextCard+1)%52, you now have a circular deck that is always random-primed. I've done this a LOT, btw. =P

Answer (score 2):

You will need to simulate a deck of cards so that when a card is selected, it is removed from a list of cards.

So what happens is that you begin with a full deck and then as you randomly pick a card from the list, you will remove it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are sampling with replacement, which means once you pick a card, you are leaving it in the deck. Take it out of the deck by removing it from your data structures. You'll need to adjust your random sampling accordingly, by changing your `cardvalue` and `cardsuit` ranges as the lengths of your arrays/vectors/whatever change.