# Shuffling a Deck of Cards , Redundancy after swapping two values

Tags: java

I was asked to write a program(mainly a method) for shuffling a deck of cards. I wrote the following program:

```
public class Deck {

////////////////////////////////////////
// Data Members
////////////////////////////////////////

private Card[] cards; // array holding all 52 cards
private int cardsInDeck; // the current number of cards in the deck

public static final int DECK_SIZE = 52;

/**
 * Shuffles the deck (i.e. randomly reorders the cards in the deck). 
 */
public void shuffle() {
    int newI;
    Card temp;
    Random randIndex = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {

        // pick a random index between 0 and cardsInDeck - 1
        newI = randIndex.nextInt(cardsInDeck);

        // swap cards[i] and cards[newI]
        temp = cards[i];
        cards[i] = cards[newI];
        cards[newI] = temp;
    }
}

}
```

But there is a logical error in the above shuffle method which is as follows: Suppose I replace Card Number 4 with Card Number 42, then I'm swapping
two times. I'm wondering is there any way of not doing this?

I checked one post here :[Shuffling a deck of cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075439/shuffling-a-deck-of-cards)

But it didn't make sense to me.

Comment: As far as I know, this is pretty much the way you swap two elements in array (for Java at least)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: The three lines doing the swap are fine, but the general approach to shuffling isn't. Fortunately, it's easily fixed.

Comment: @JonSkeet I had to go away a smack my head against a wall for few minutes but I see what you mean, the OP is shuffling the "entire" list on each iterations, where they really should be shuffling a ever decreasing range... clear as mud ;)

Comment: Use Fisher Yates.  This method is proven to not have an even distribution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm wondering is there any way of not doing this?

Absolutely. Instead of swapping one card with *any* other, simply swap one card with a *later* one.

So at any point, you're really picking which card is going to be in slot `i` from "all the remaining cards" which haven't been picked. It's *conceptually* equivalent to starting with one list of cards, and *removing* cards at random to place in the new shuffled collection. The fact that you're actually swapping locations while you're doing that is irrelevant, as at any point you'll be picking uniformly randomly from the remaining slots.

Read the [Wikipedia article on the Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for more information.

(Some implementations swap from the *end*, so element `x` is swapped with a random element in the range `[0, x]`. That's equivalent to what I described, just mirrored. Personally I find it easier to think of the *first* part of the collection as being the shuffled part at any point, but that's a failing on my part rather than an inherent difference.)

Also bear in mind that if you use a `List<Card>`, you can use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) and avoid having to write the code for this at all.

Answer (score 7):

You can compare your implementation with Collections.shuffle, that one definitely works right, this is a snippet from src

```
  // Shuffle array
  for (int i=size; i > 1; i--)
      swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

...

   private static void swap(Object[] arr, int i, int j) {
        Object tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, the best way to shuffle a deck is to *not* shuffle it. Since you already know how to use random numbers, you can use a modification to the Fisher-Yates shuffle to extract cards in random order, without duplicates, all without an initial sort.

Think of it in these physical terms (when using a real deck of cards). Rather than shuffling the deck up front then continuously extracting the top card, just leave the deck in sorted order and extract a card from a random location each time.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299138/generate-n-random-and-unique-numbers-within-a-range/4299337#4299337) for an complete explanation of how this works but I'll cover extracting three numbers from 1 through 9 inclusive below.

---

Start with the (unshuffled) list `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` (of length 9, obviously) and generate a random number based on that length (from 0 to 8 inclusive, assuming we use zero-based indexes, which Java does). Let's say the first random number is 4.

You then save the item at position number 4 (which is `5`) and move the _last item in the list (`9`) to that position, decreasing the length by one. That gives you `{1,2,3,4,9,6,7,8}` with a length of 8.

Then go back for a second number again using a random number based on the length (0 through 7 inclusive). In this case, we'll get the random number 1.

The item at offset 1 is `2` and we then adjust the list same as the first step, giving `{1,8,3,4,9,6,7}` with a length of 7.

Now let's say we get a third random number based on the current length of 7 and it happens to be 4 again. That item is now `9` so we return that, after modifying the list to become `{1,8,3,4,7,6}` with length 6.

You should be able to see how this is developing. Without any worry about sorting the entire list up front, you can achieve a random sequence (well, as random as your random number generator permits) without repeats.

Comment: Why do you need to move the last to that position?  Just remove items.

Comment: @Paparazzi, the answers assumes nothing more than a simple array so no delete operator. If you have a vector-type collection, it's likely to be less efficient since the items above are all shifted down.