# How to shuffle a String array without using library and sort method?

Tags: java, arrays, string, shuffle

I'm writing a deck with 52 cards. Everything is perfect but I can't figure out how to shuffle it without using any library from java and using the sort method built into java.  Here is my code. I been trying to figure something out for a while and so far I'm unable to.

```
String [] deck2=new String [52];
String[] deck=new String [52];
String suits[]={"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
String rank[]={"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","King","Queen","Ace"};

for(int i=0;i<deck.length;i++){
    deck[i]=rank[i%13]+" "+"of "+suits[i/13];
    deck2[i]=deck[i];
    System.out.println(deck[i]);

}}}
```

Comment: You can use Math.Random()

Comment: I think this answer is helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313567/shuffling-a-deck-of-cards-redundancy-after-swapping-two-values/16313657#16313657

Comment: No I can't use any built in library like math random or sort. It has to be everything on on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. After all, a library is nothing more than some code you could as well write yourself. You'll have to write your own random number generator. This is one simple example:

```
private static long x = System.currentTimeMillis();

public static long rndNumber() {
    x ^= (x << 21);
    x ^= (x >>> 35);
    x ^= (x << 4);
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

public static void shuffle(int a[]) {
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int pos = (int) (rndNumber() % a.length);
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[pos];
        a[pos] = temp;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    shuffle(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Comment: For using Fisher-Yates shuffle, which is both O(n) and as fair as the random number generator, +1

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    int from = (int) (Math.random() * array.length); //The place to get the first from
    int to = (int) (Math.random() * array.length); // The place to get the second from
    String perm = array[from]; // Store the "from" value
    array[from] = array[to]; // Set the first value to the second
    array[to] = perm; // Set the second value to the first
}
```

I don't know, why you don't want to use a java built-in library, they are there for a reason.

To create a random number without any built in methods is hard. I found a way long time ago, using float, and making it overflow

```
float random = 1 << 32 + 1256224; //Have a random number here, it doesn't matter
```

I didn't tested it, this may not work.

```
float random = 1 << 32 + 1256224;
String [] deck2=new String [52];
String[] deck=new String [52];
String suits[]={"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
String rank[]={"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","King","Queen","Ace"};

for(int i=0;i<deck.length;i++){
    deck[i]=rank[i%13]+" "+"of "+suits[i/13];
    deck2[i]=deck[i];
    System.out.println(deck[i]);

}
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    int from = (int) (Math.random() * array.length); //The place to get the first from
    int to = (int) (Math.random() * array.length); // The place to get the second from
    String perm = array[from]; // Store the "from" value
    array[from] = array[to]; // Set the first value to the second
    array[to] = perm; // Set the second value to the first
}
```

}}

Comment: I can't use math random either. It's a built in library.

Comment: I'm learning java on my own and someone told me to the best way to learn it would be to see how a array list works. I'm trying to do it would out using any library in java. Trying to sort all on my own.

Comment: That's really really nice. Again, why can't you use them? I edit my post, and I include a way to solve this

Comment: @KingJames Guess what, ArrayList does use built-in libraries.

Comment: My friend was able to do it without a built in library and I'm just trying to figure out how he did it.

Comment: @KingJames your friend is probably lying.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was any way for me to do it without using any library.

Comment: @KingJames Did your friend said without "built-in" library or just library?

Comment: @KingJames I edited my post with a possible solution, check it out,

Comment: Any built in library so I shouldn't be able to import any thing or use any built in sort methods. It has to be everything on my own.

Comment: @KingJames Again, try what I posted above. Check out our friend's coe though, I have a prettygood feeling he is lying.

Comment: Can't I just use some method to make it in ascending order or defending order.

Comment: @KingJames Do you want it in ascending or descending order, or yo you wan to shuffle it?

Comment: I would prefer shuffling but trying it in ascending order or desending order is pretty much the same as shuffling.

Comment: Why not use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is as fair as the random number generator and only needs n-1 steps?

Comment: @KingJames Avoiding libraries will not let you learn real Java coding, which centers around picking the right library for the job.

Comment: @KingJames Also James, I don't know how I could say this to you, but...String is also a built-in class.