# Correct logic to randomly select a card from deck until all cards are selected

Tags: java, math, random, logic

I need some advice here. I want to create a logic to randomly select one card at a time from a deck of 52 cards until all cards are selected, if all 52 cards are used, i need to reshuffle the deck and start again.

I already created a logic for this which is working fine, but I think there should be some better way to do this. Some MMM - Maths Master Minds can end my misery.

Here is the logic:

1. Create an empty arraylist to store the all 52 cards for checking
2. Select a card randomly and check if that exist in the arraylist
3. if yes, repeat step 2
4. if no, add the card to arraylist
5. if arraylist size is 52, empty the arraylist

   ```
   ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   int card = -1;

   do {
       Random random = new Random();
       card = random.nextInt(52);
   } while (list.contains(card) == true);

   // code for drawing the card by the number
   list.add(card);
   ```

**Only problem with this logic is when there is only one card left, there is less than 2% chances of getting that card by random. System is spending a lot of time to find the card. It keep checking that do while loop. 


Please suggest improvements and thanks for your time.**

Comment: I don't see how your loop ends.

Comment: It's not a very efficient solution, but I really doubt that the system would spend a lot of time doing this. Computers are very very fast.

Comment: Computers are almost fast as Usain Bolt.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun i think this loop is fine, can you please point out the mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to instead start with a full arraylist containing all the cards and then remove a random index until the list is empty, at which time you would refill it.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
    list.add(i+1);
}
int c = 52;
Random random = new Random();
while(c>0){
    int r = random.nextInt(c--);
    int card = list.get(r);
    list.remove(r);
}
resetList();
```

Comment: it would be same Alex, dont you think?

Comment: It's not the same at all, there are no retries with this logic. +1

Comment: in this case you would not need to check if the card is in the list.

Comment: @Alex can, you explain with some code? I think i din't get you correctly.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I din't think that way, Really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling cards from the deck in a random sequence is the same as shuffling the deck and then pulling out cards from first to last. So you might find [Shuffling a deck of cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075439/shuffling-a-deck-of-cards) helpful.